# DeepLink with google actions. First ask is never called

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I have verified the app and the website. Deeplink works. But the issue is with the ask conversation. If you put 2 asks, only the last one will be executed but not the first. So for example:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Great! Looks like we can do that in the app.')
  conv.ask(new DeepLink({
    destination: 'Google',
    url: 'example://gizmos',
    package: 'com.example.gizmos',
    reason: 'handle this for you',
  }))
})
```

**This will show:**

Can I send you to the Google mobile app to handle this for you?

**This is what i want:**

Great! Looks like we can do that in the app.

Can I send you to the Google mobile app to handle this for you?

Comment: You may want to file an issue on the library's [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues)

Comment: I'll do that thanks :)

Comment: Did you test it in the simulator? What surface did you use?

Comment: I tried both. Simulator and on device.